# Being thrown a stupid bracket error. Also unsure on how to continue

Tags: java, oop, bluej

So I have the following classes:

```
public class Vehicle
{
    private double horsepower;
    private double weight;
    private double topspeed;

    public Vehicle (double HP, double Heavy, double TSpeed)
    {
        horsepower = HP;
        weight = Heavy;
        topspeed = TSpeed;
    }

    //public double Consumption
}
```

.

```
public class SportCar extends Vehicle
{
    public double aerodynamic;

    public void Aero
    {
        aerodynamic = 0.5;
    }
}
```

.

```
 public class TestConsumption
 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Vehicle first = new Vehicle(200, 1500, 220);
        Vehicle second = new Vehicle(100, 1000, 170);
        Vehicle third = new Vehicle(135, 1100.2, 173);
    }
}
```

And I'm being given an error that looks says `'('` expected in the fifth line of the SportCar class. I have no idea why its giving this error so I'm super stuck.

Additionally, I'm trying to use the horsepower, weight, topspeed and aerodynamic properties in a formula to provide a consumption value. I'm not sure where to go forward with what I've done so far - any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: The `()` are missing on your `Aero` method declaration.

Comment: And you missing a constructor for the SportCar class?

Comment: SO only really works if you keep it to one question per post.

Comment: What kind of syntax do you believe `public void Aero` is, and have you checked that you're using the right syntax for what you're trying to achieve? (You're not, and the compiler is telling you exactly what's wrong...)

Comment: Yeah I've figured my mistake. Anyone have any idea where I can learn this stuff from online? I don't exactly have the best lecturer, you see

Comment: There are *loads* of Java tutorials available - but I'd also recommend getting a good book. (You might want to start with Head First Java.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer why you are getting the missing bracket, you need to add `()` after your `public void Aero` like so:

```
public void Aero()
```

However, since it extends Vehicle, you would also require the same parameters as in your main constructor for your Vehicle class.

```
public void Aero(double HP, double Heavy, double TSpeed){
//to-do logic
}
```

As for creating a consumption value, you would need to identify how the three variables (or 4 for Aero), affect the outcome of it.  For example: `HP * TSpeed * Heavy`.  Now, I'm no engineer and I would not know the correct formula to use.